Entity Framework - Registering a repository implementation with different interfaces
In our codebase we have a repository class that has this inheritance pattern:
public interface IReadOnlyRepository 
{
   public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
}

public interface IReadWriteRepository : IReadOnlyRepository{}
{
   public void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity

   public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity

   // more CRUD methods etc
}

public class Repository(IReadWriteRepository repo) : IReadWriteRepository
{
   public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
   {
      // implementation
   }

   public void Add<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
   {
      // implementation
   }

   // rest of CRUD method implementations
}

Then when registering services, we register two instances of the Repository class, but with different interface definitions using the factory pattern:
// Read write repo
services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadWriteRepository, p => new Repository(p.GetRequiredService<DbContext>));

// Read only repo
services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository, p => new Repository(p.GetRequiredService<DbContext>));

Question is, will the second registration still only have access to the Get() method of IReadOnlyRepository even if we register it as the base type with method definitions for all the CRUD methods? If so, what happens to the CRUD methods in this case? Are they just not included in the read only version of Repository?

The code is fundamentally broken. This is an ugly antipattern. EF doesn't need to be wrapped in low-level CRUD classes. EF is an ORM, a far higher abstraction that tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects or an object database, NOT database drivers. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection or model. The single entity Repository is DbSet and no, it doesn't have CRUD methods because it doesn't need them

If this follows the typicall antipattern, the "Delete" method can easily perform 42 pending Updates while Insert can perform 37 Deletes. SaveChanges persists all pending changes, not just the latest one. There won't be any way to roll back the changes either. When DbContext is used properly, all one needs to do to discard changes is to not call SaveChanges and dispose the DbContext. This pseudo-repository doesn't abstract anything, it tries to bring the implementation that EF had abstracted away to the front

As for the exact question, there's no inheritance relation between the two interfaces. Worse, they aren't what they claim as the CRUD class isn't read-only. You can create real read-only DbContexts or just queries by disabling tracking either in the configuration or the query itself

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for taking the time to reply, but you didn't answer the question.
To clarify, the IRepository class here is used basically as a facade to the DbContext. The CRUD classes implementations are facades of the DbContext.Add(), Update() etc. I simplified the code significantly as it's irrelevant to the question, hence why I didn't include the actual implementations either.
The reason for these is that we can set timestamps on when entities are added and updated etc. automatically.

The concept is that the read-only repository is a subset of a read-write repository, hence the inheritance. Otherwise, you could drop the inheritance pattern and just define a Get() method in the IReadWriteRepository but why?
The main question here is about registering the services. I didn't really write this code to begin with and is of the opinion that the IReadOnlyRepository should have its own implementation altogether.

If you want actual read-only behavior you must disable change tracking. This isn't about registration at all. Nothing prevents someone from just casting IReadOnlyRepository  to Repository and start deleting. Sure, any class requesting IReadOnlyRepository will get just that interface, but the actual type is the full CRUD class

we can set timestamps on when entities are added and updated the solution to that is to use either database triggers or SaveChanges interceptors. Auditing is the actual documentation example. I understood the question perfectly. There are several similar questions every week, where people ask how to solve the bugs caused by putting DbContext inside CRUD classes

The answer to your exact question is that the Repository you register with IReadOnlyRepository is still writable, and the CUD methods are accessible through casting. To ensure read-only behavior you'd have to create a DbContext with change tracking disabled. You can avoid creating two DbContext types by using a factory method that uses DbCongtextOptionsBuilder.UseQueryTracckingBehavior to disable change tracking.

@PanagiotisKanavos - I am always reading your comments (because the Entity Framework is one of your strongest point from what I saw) and I know how much u hate the concept on Unit Of Work over Entity Framework, but I am using it in my shared projects to have a common place for methods that access the DB and to avoid code duplication and the returns are DTOs, also the unit tests are lighter right now. I just want to know your opinion about this usage approach and what other architectural options u consider... I really appreciate your solutions and opinions that u  present on stackoverflow.

@DA no, I don't hate UoW over EF. DbContext is a Unit of Work. I hate low level CRUDs over Unit-of-Work, the same way eg Oren Eini does  because people misunderstood some books. That's not an opinion or architectural choice. If you misuse a tool, you suffer the consequences. And increase code duplication.

@DA the Domain Repository pattern specified in DDD isn't a CRUD class, doesn't return a single type only,  and does increase the abstraction level. It's specific to the scenario and can return all the entities needed for a specific bounded context/scenario/use case and let you make the changes you want without database-related CRUD methods. Creating such a Domain Repository with EF would be very easy, as all you'd had to do is write the LINQ queries that return the objects you need, and the UoW implementation would be just an IDisposable.

@DA the same Domain Repository API with a MongoDB, Neo4j or CRUD relational backend wouldn't change. Both document and graph databases are closer to object concepts though, so a CRUD interface over MongoDB documents or Neo4j would once again cause more problems than it solves. An entire blog may be a single document, so how do you create separate CRUDs for Blog and Post ?

@DA as for common place, DTOs, lighter tests, I have that too. I have a Tickets repo with ticket files stored on disk, so I can check if a ticket is already downloaded and retrieve it. The same repo can target S3 or MinIO. No CRUDs involved though, just Exists, Save, and a Get that uses ticket number, airline, etc, not the actual file path

I explained why this is an antipattern in the comments - this code wraps a high-level Unit-of-Work with a low-level CRUD class, not a Repository. The Repository class itself is still writeable and someone can just cast IReadOnlyRepository to IReadWriteRepository or even directly to Repository and start deleting. It's as simple as :
(_myReadOnlyRepo as Repository).Delete(something);

Even worse, the objects returned by IReadOnlyRepository<TEntity>.Get will be fully tracked, which means any change made to them could get persisted, even without casting. If a Controller has both an IReadOnlyRepository and a IReadWriteRepository dependency then both of them will use the same DbContext instance. Someone could eg load blog posts from the "read-only" repo, make modifications to them and then update votes in the other repository. That Update would also persist the changes to the blog posts.
DbContext is a Unit-of-Work that detects changes to all the objects it tracks, so the way to make it read-only is to disable change tracking. This is possible either for individual queries with AsNoTracking() or for the entire DbContext with a call to DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior() during configuration.
In a proper Domain Repository someone could disable at just the query level, eg :
public Blog GetBlogPostsForRendering(int blogId,DateOnly since)
{
    var blogAndPosts = _context.Blog.AsNoTracking()
                               .Include(b=>b.Posts.Where(p=>p.Created>=since))
                               .ToList();
    return blogAndPosts;
}

In the question's case, the entire DbContext instance has to be made read-only. This can be done with UseQueryTrackingBehavior eg :
services.AddScoped<IReadOnlyRepository>(p => {
    var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test")
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
        .Options;
    var context=new MyContext(options);
    return new Repository(context);
});

To avoid duplication the common configuration options can be extracted to a separate method :
DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext> ContextConfiguration(
    IServiceProvider services,
    bool readonly)
{
  var config=services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
  var cns=config.GetConnectionString("mydb");
  var builder=new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(cns)
        ...;
  if(readonly)
  {
      builder=builder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
  }
  return builder;
}

...
services.AddScoped<IReadOnlyRepository>(p => {
    var contextOptions = ContextConfiguration(p,true).Options;
    var context=new MyContext(options);
    return new Repository(context);
});

